# avoid (in operator) with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

How do I change the use of the `IN` operator in the following statement:

```
select stdId, stdName from students where stdId in (:stdsIds)
```

Comment: what do you want to change about it

Comment: I think you should have this tagged as Oracle instead of SQL Server

Comment: @cBlaine If you look at the original edit, OP wrote "I am using SQL server currently." I removed [tag:oracle]. It seems they wanted to *convert* the query from Oracle to SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you can avoid `IN` when you have more than one table involved

If you have something like

```
SELECT name 
FROM students s 
WHERE student_id IN ( SELECT student_id 
                      FROM courses 
                      WHERE course_id = 1 
                    );
```

In that case, you could use `EXISTS`

```
SELECT name 
FROM students s 
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
               FROM courses c
               WHERE c.student_id = s.student_id
                 AND c.course_id = 1
              );
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an EXISTS statement instead.  So your query would change to this:

```
select stdId, stdName from students where exists(:stdsIds where stdId = students.stdId)
```

EDIT: I don't use Oracle but I "think" the syntax would look something like this:

```
select stdId, stdName from students where exists(:stdsIds = students.stdId)
```